# Travel to UK when visa (BRP) expiry due within a month 14th May

Tags: united-kingdom

I have a valid BRP which is due to expire on 14th of May and travelled to India due to a medical emergency.

Can I travel back to UK when visa is about to expire within weeks  ?

Comment: Are you intending to renew your residence permit? If so, have you asked for a renewal?

Comment: I got to know extension should not be done when am outside UK as per below statement                                                                You must not travel outside of the UK, Ireland, the Channel Islands or the Isle of Man until you get a decision. Your application will be withdrawn if you do.

Comment: AFAIK, a valid visa and BRP allows you to enter and stay in the UK up to the expiry date of your visa. If your **BRP** (but not your visa) expires while you are outside the UK you’ll need to apply for a ‘replacement BRP visa’, which lets you re-enter the UK once only https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/replace-expired-brp

Comment: I think I might have confused with above statement

Comment: Am currently on a skilled worker visa and my brp is due to expire on 14th May . Iam outside UK currently and checking if I can postpone my travel to next week while leaves me with 2 weeks for BRP to expire